# RGB to CMY color model using c++

Tags: c++, image-processing, colors, cmyk

This is the formula that we use to convert RGB to respective CMY format:

```
C = 1 - ( R / 255 )
M = 1 - ( G / 255 )
Y = 1 - ( B / 255 )
```

I am trying to display the CMY image after applying this formula to RGB values of the original image, but the resultant values that I get are between 0 and 1. I don't think this range can be used to display an image.

How do I store CMY values as an array so that they can be used to display the image?
Do I have to scale the range of 0-1 to 0-255 for that?

If I have to scale then, why this formula is used, I can directly use:

```
C = 255 - R
M = 255 - G
Y = 255 - B
```

Comment: Make an array and put the values in it?

Comment: what do you mean by storing in an array? How are RGB values stored in the code?

Comment: Also, using integers will not get you a value _between_ `0` and `1`. It will give you _either_ `0` or `1`.

Comment: You will need to know what decimal precision you want, because their are infinite between 0 and 1.

Comment: Honestly that is the best way of doing it, you are fine.

Comment: Maybe if you tell us what exactly you are trying to do with these numbers so we can better understand.

Comment: I will edit the question .. may be that will help!

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    float C = 1.0f - (R / 255.0f);
    float M = 1.0f - (G / 255.0f);
    float Y = 1.0f - (B / 255.0f);

    float cmyArray[3] = {C, M, Y};
    return 0;
}
```

This code will store the `C`, `M`, `Y` variables as `floating points` and then create an array for 3 `floating points` to be pushed in. In this case it starts off with the values `C`, `M`, and `Y` already initialized into the array.

Answer (score 0):

Like this: http://liveworkspace.org/code/2rpyRF$2

If you need many values then you could address the nth cmy group as such: `n*3 + x` where x is 0 for c, 1 for m and 2 for y.